# NotSerializableException in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline

In my Jenkins pipeline script there is a step where I unzip a file to a different directory. I used the Ant unzip method for this without issues until recently.
Recently I upgraded the Jenkins version from 2.319.2 (LTS) to 2.346.2 (LTS) and started facing issues with this step. I have upgraded the plugins to their allowed version now, yet I am facing issues.

When I use the ant unzip method, I get a ClassCastException. Changing it to unzip from pipeline-utility-steps plugin causes NotSerializableException.

The code is question...

```
def ant = new AntBuilder();
String configFile = "${WORKSPACE}/target/configuration.zip";
if (new File(configFile).exists()) {
   ant.unzip(  src:"${WORKSPACE}/target/configuration.zip",
   dest:"${WORKSPACE}/",
   overwrite:"true" );
}
```

The error...

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.apache.xerces.parsers.XIncludeAwareParserConfiguration cannot be cast to class org.apache.xerces.xni.parser.XMLParserConfiguration (org.apache.xerces.parsers.XIncludeAwareParserConfiguration is in unnamed module of loader org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell$CleanGroovyClassLoader @359d4f06; org.apache.xerces.xni.parser.XMLParserConfiguration is in unnamed module of loader org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell$CleanGroovyClassLoader @9e05a28)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl.newSAXParser(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.util.JAXPUtils.newSAXParser(JAXPUtils.java:217)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.util.JAXPUtils.getNamespaceXMLReader(JAXPUtils.java:174)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.ProjectHelper2.parse(ProjectHelper2.java:247)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.ProjectHelper2.parseUnknownElement(ProjectHelper2.java:134)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.ProjectHelper2.parseAntlibDescriptor(ProjectHelper2.java:114)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Antlib.createAntlib(Antlib.java:95)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Definer.loadAntlib(Definer.java:416)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Definer.execute(Definer.java:275)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.ComponentHelper.checkNamespace(ComponentHelper.java:853)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.ComponentHelper.getDefinition(ComponentHelper.java:308)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.ComponentHelper.createComponent(ComponentHelper.java:285)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.ComponentHelper.createComponent(ComponentHelper.java:264)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.makeObject(UnknownElement.java:434)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.maybeConfigure(UnknownElement.java:166)
    at groovy.util.AntBuilder.performTask(AntBuilder.java:333)
    at groovy.util.AntBuilder.nodeCompleted(AntBuilder.java:283)
    at groovy.util.BuilderSupport.doInvokeMethod(BuilderSupport.java:154)
    at groovy.util.AntBuilder.doInvokeMethod(AntBuilder.java:218)
    at groovy.util.BuilderSupport.invokeMethod(BuilderSupport.java:67)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.DefaultInvoker.methodCall(DefaultInvoker.java:20)
Caused: 
    at groovy.util.AntBuilder.performTask(AntBuilder.java:351)
    at groovy.util.AntBuilder.nodeCompleted(AntBuilder.java:283)
    at groovy.util.BuilderSupport.doInvokeMethod(BuilderSupport.java:154)
    at groovy.util.AntBuilder.doInvokeMethod(AntBuilder.java:218)
    at groovy.util.BuilderSupport.invokeMethod(BuilderSupport.java:67)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.DefaultInvoker.methodCall(DefaultInvoker.java:20)
    at DeployESBApplications.run(DeployESBApplications.groovy:94)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:86)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:113)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:83)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor145.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CollectionLiteralBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatch(CollectionLiteralBlock.java:55)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CollectionLiteralBlock$ContinuationImpl.item(CollectionLiteralBlock.java:45)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor237.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:136)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:275)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:187)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:420)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$400(CpsThreadGroup.java:95)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:330)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:294)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:67)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:139)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Changing the code to use the unzip from utiliy-steps plugin as

```
def ant = new AntBuilder();
String configFile = "${WORKSPACE}/target/configuration.zip";
if (new File(configFile).exists()) {
   unzip zipFile: "${WORKSPACE}/target/configuration.zip", dir:"${WORKSPACE}/"
}
```

causes the following error

```
an exception which occurred:
    in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.BlockScopeEnv.locals
    in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.BlockScopeEnv@1f6e89bf
    in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ProxyEnv.parent
    in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.BlockScopeEnv@a65f0f0
    in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CallEnv.caller
    in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ClosureCallEnv@4261960d
    in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ProxyEnv.parent
    in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.BlockScopeEnv@5a6e0fbb
    in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ProxyEnv.parent
    in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.BlockScopeEnv@5be9cee5
    in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CallEnv.caller
    in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallEnv@2d9caa03
    in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.e
    in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable@2a097c2a
    in field org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.program
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread@1f37a462
    in field org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.threads
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup@d32794c
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup@d32794c
Caused: java.io.NotSerializableException: sun.nio.fs.UnixPath
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:274)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.doWriteObject(BlockMarshaller.java:65)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.writeObject(BlockMarshaller.java:56)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.MarshallerObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(MarshallerObjectOutputStream.java:50)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(RiverObjectOutputStream.java:179)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:345)
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.internalWriteEntries(HashMap.java:1858)
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1412)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.JDKSpecific$SerMethods.callWriteObject(JDKSpecific.java:89)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.SerializableClass.callWriteObject(SerializableClass.java:199)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1089)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:268)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1143)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1101)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:268)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1143)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1101)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1080)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:268)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1143)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1101)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1080)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:268)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1143)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1101)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1080)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:268)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1143)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1101)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1080)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:268)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1143)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1101)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1080)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:268)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1143)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1101)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:268)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1143)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1101)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:268)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.doWriteObject(BlockMarshaller.java:65)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.writeObject(BlockMarshaller.java:56)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.MarshallerObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(MarshallerObjectOutputStream.java:50)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(RiverObjectOutputStream.java:179)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:345)
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.internalWriteEntries(HashMap.java:1858)
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1412)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.JDKSpecific$SerMethods.callWriteObject(JDKSpecific.java:89)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.SerializableClass.callWriteObject(SerializableClass.java:199)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1089)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:268)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1143)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1101)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:268)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractObjectOutput.writeObject(AbstractObjectOutput.java:58)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractMarshaller.writeObject(AbstractMarshaller.java:116)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.pickles.serialization.RiverWriter.lambda$writeObject$1(RiverWriter.java:144)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.runInSandbox(GroovySandbox.java:331)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.pickles.serialization.RiverWriter.writeObject(RiverWriter.java:143)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.saveProgram(CpsThreadGroup.java:578)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.saveProgram(CpsThreadGroup.java:554)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.saveProgramIfPossible(CpsThreadGroup.java:537)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:461)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$400(CpsThreadGroup.java:95)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:330)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:294)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:67)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:139)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Weirdly, the configuration.zip is unzipped as expected. But after unzip is completed, the above exception is thrown and the job fails.

Even a simple sh command for the unzip is causing the above exception to be thrown and the job to fail..

Please help me in rectifying this error.

Tried updating the plugins to the latest, still the issue is present.

Some details about the setup.
Jenkins is running in a docker container on the Unix server.

```
Versions are
Jenkins : v2.346.2 (LTS)
Plugins::
Pipeline : 590.v6a_d052e5a_a_b_5
Pipeline Utility Steps : 2.13.1
Pipeline: API : 1200.v8005c684b_a_c6
Pipeline: Basic Steps : 994.vd57e3ca_46d24
Pipeline: Groovy : 2803.v1a_f77ffcc773
Pipeline: Groovy Libraries : 613.v9c41a_160233f
```

Will share the details of the other plugins if needed.

---

Edited to add the complete pipeline.

```
@Grapes(
        @Grab(group='org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder', module='http-builder', version='0.7.1')
)

/**
 *
 * This file is responsible to deploy the ESB applications by pulling the Application's artifact from the artifactory.
 *
 */

import static groovy.io.FileType.FILES
import groovyx.net.http.RESTClient
import java.nio.file.*
import java.nio.files.*

def AUTHENTICATION_TOKEN = null;
def REGISTRATION_TOKEN = null;
def ORGANIZATION_ID = null;
def ENVIRONMENT_ID = null;
def MULE_INSTANCE_NAME = null;
def APPSERVERNAME = null;
def TARGET_ID = null;

// Set some environment variables

List servList;
def hostNamesMap = [:];
/**
 * Loading of the parameters from the deploy_esb_parameters.groovy file
 */
stage('Load Parameter Script'){
        if(JOB_NAME == 'Deploy-ESB-Applications-uat') {
                evaluate(new File("$HUDSON_HOME/parameters/deploy_esb_ARM_parameters_uat.groovy"))
        } else if(JOB_NAME == 'Deploy-ESB-Applications-pfix'){
                evaluate(new File("$HUDSON_HOME/parameters/deploy_esb_ARM_parameters_prod_fix.groovy"))
        } else if(JOB_NAME == 'Deploy-ESB-Applications-prod' || JOB_NAME == 'Deploy-ESB-Applications_PROD'){
                evaluate(new File("$HUDSON_HOME/parameters/deploy_esb_ARM_parameters_prod.groovy"))
        } else {
                evaluate(new File("$HUDSON_HOME/parameters/deploy_esb_ARM_parameters.groovy"))
        }
}

try{
        node {
                // Load the libraries to access the common functions
                script = load "$HUDSON_HOME/libraries/esb_common_functions.groovy"
                commonScript = load "$HUDSON_HOME/libraries/pipeline_common_functions.groovy"

                stage('Set up deploy environment'){
                        // Code stripped for brevity
                }

                stage("Download Application and set Properties") {
                        if (BUILD_TO_DEPLOY != null && BUILD_TO_DEPLOY.trim().length() > 0){
                                commonScript.printDebugMessage("Downloading artifact(.zip) from the path ${artifactRepository}/${BUILD_TO_DEPLOY}/ to the target path $WORKSPACE/./target..."   )

                                def status = ''
                                withCredentials([[$class: 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding', credentialsId: 'rsa-developer', usernameVariable: 'username', passwordVariable: 'password']]){

                                        status = commonScript.downloadFromArtifactory(env.username, env.password, ARTIFACTORY_URL, "${artifactRepository}/${BUILD_TO_DEPLOY}/*.*", "./")
                                        //status = commonScript.downloadFromArtifactory(env.username, env.password, ARTIFACTORY_URL, "${artifactRepository}/${BUILD_TO_DEPLOY}/pom.xml", "./")
                                }
                                if(!status){
                                        error('Error while retrieving artifact from artifactory')
                                }else {
                                        Path source = Paths.get("${WORKSPACE}/${BUILD_TO_DEPLOY}/");
                                        Path target = Paths.get("${WORKSPACE}/target/");
                                        Files.move(source, target);

                                        //def ant = new AntBuilder();
                                        //String configFile = "${WORKSPACE}/target/configuration.zip";
                                        //if (new File(configFile).exists()) {
                                                        //ant.unzip(  src:"${WORKSPACE}/target/configuration.zip",
                                                        //dest:"${WORKSPACE}/",
                                                        //overwrite:"true" );
                                                        
                                                        // Not working
                                                        //unzip zipFile: "${WORKSPACE}/target/configuration.zip", dir: "${WORKSPACE}/"

                                                        // Not working
                                                        //sh script: """unzip -o "${WORKSPACE}/target/configuration.zip -d "${WORKSPACE}/" """, returnStdout:true
                                        //}

                                        //testing
                                        //@NonCPS def unzipCommand = {
                                                        //ant.unzip(  src:"${WORKSPACE}/target/configuration.zip",
                                                        //dest:"${WORKSPACE}/",
                                                        //overwrite:"true" );

                                        //              unzip zipFile: "${WORKSPACE}/target/configuration.zip", dir: "${WORKSPACE}/"
                                        //      }
                                        //unzipCommand.call()
                                        def result = unzipConfig();

                                        if(result)
                                            commonScript.printDebugMessage("*** Unzipping the configuration.zip is complete")
                                        else
                                            commonScript.printDebugMessage("*** Unzipping the configuration.zip FAILED")
                                }
                        } else {
                                commonScript.printDebugMessage("No artifact chosen to download")
                                currentBuild.result='FAILURE'
                                error("Download failed")
                        }

                        script.setCLIVars(envList);
                        script.replacePlaceholdersInLog4j2();

                        // Fetch details about MULE Instance and verify it is up and running
                        // Code stripped for brevity

                }

                stage ('Set Hostnames'){
                        // Code stripped for brevity
                }

                stage('Prepare property files'){
                        // Code stripped for brevity
                }

                stage('Reset Database'){
                        // Code stripped for brevity
                }

                stage('Anypoint Runtime Manager Setup & Deployment'){
                        // Code stripped for brevity
                }

                stage('Cleanup & Notify'){
                        // Code stripped for brevity
                }
        }

}catch (e) {
        currentBuild.result = "FAILED";
        throw e;
} finally {
}


@NonCPS
def boolean unzipConfig() {
        boolean isSuccess = true;
        try {
                def ant = new AntBuilder();
                String configFile = "${WORKSPACE}/target/configuration.zip";
                if(new File(configFile).exists()) {
                        //ant.unzip(  src:"${WORKSPACE}/target/configuration.zip",
                        //      dest:"${WORKSPACE}/",
                        //      overwrite:"true" );
                        unzip zipFile: "${WORKSPACE}/target/configuration.zip", dir: "${WORKSPACE}/"

                } else {
                        commonScript.printDebugMessage("configuration.zip file not found");
                }
        } catch (Exception e) {
                isSuccess = false;
                currentBuild.result='FAILED';
                commonScript.printDebugMessage("" + e);
        }
        return isSuccess;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move your code to an external `@NonCPS` function and call the function from your Pipeline.

```
@NonCPS
def unZip() {
  def ant = new AntBuilder();
  String configFile = "${WORKSPACE}/target/configuration.zip";
  if (new File(configFile).exists()) {
     ant.unzip(  src:"${WORKSPACE}/target/configuration.zip",
     dest:"${WORKSPACE}/",
     overwrite:"true" );
  }
}
```

Comment: I made the following @NonCPS function. It still fails.

`@NonCPS
def boolean unzipConfig() {
        boolean isSuccess = true;
        try {
                def ant = new AntBuilder();
                ant.unzip(  src:"${WORKSPACE}/target/configuration.zip",
                        dest:"${WORKSPACE}/",
                        overwrite:"true" );
        } catch (Exception e) {
                isSuccess = false;
                currentBuild.result='FAILED';
                commonScript.printDebugMessage("" + e);
        }
        return isSuccess;
}`

Comment: What's failing? Wat errors do you get?

Comment: when I use the above block, I get the same error as above (ClassCastException).

If I use the unzip from utility-steps plugin, I get a the same NotSerializedException as above. But there is one additional log line...
`expected to call DeployESBApplications.unzipConfig but wound up catching unzip; see: https://jenkins.io/redirect/pipeline-cps-method-mismatches/`

Comment: Add your full pipeline to the question.

Comment: added the complete pipeline. non relevant portions have been truncated.